# How do I properly set up an API call using useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, react-functional-component

Here is my entire component. In the console the correct data is showing up at "data" but when I try to run map on it it says "map is not a function." The 16 items in the console are the correct beaches.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export default function Beaches() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({beaches: []})
    // const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false)


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchBeaches = async () => {
            const result = await axios('http://localhost:3000/beaches');
            setData(result.data);}
            fetchBeaches();
        }, [])
            
    console.log(data)


return (

    <ul>
        {data.beaches.map(beach => (
            <button>{beach.name}</button>
        ))}
    </ul>
)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not setting the beaches data in state correctly.

Replace `useEffect` code with this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchBeaches = async () => {
    const result = await axios('http://localhost:3000/beaches');
    setData({beaches: result.data});
  }
  fetchBeaches();
}, [])
```

furthermore, you can improve the state structure of beaches data:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Beaches() {
  const [beaches, setBeaches] = useState([]);
  // const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBeaches = async () => {
      const result = await axios("http://localhost:3000/beaches");
      setBeaches(result.data);
    };
    fetchBeaches();
  }, []);


  return (
    <ul>
      {beaches.map((beach) => (
        <button>{beach.name}</button>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```